# What is the reason for my 74LS08 Quad AND gates' weird behavior?

Tags: digital-logic

I have a simple circuit that consists of three binary counters that are 74LS161 in cascade, three 74LS08 AND Gates and a Flip Flop.

The AND Gates connected to the output of the counters recognize when a certain number is reached and set or reset the Flip Flop.

What I noticed with the oscilloscope is that the output's wave is correct when I put the AND Gates in a certain order, but it is incorrect and random when I switch the AND chips.

All components are brand new. What I don't understand is that if one of them was broken, the output should not be right in any case.

Comment: There are only four AND gates in a 74LS08 - have you tried checking them? I guess you're using a breadboard: it's easy to put a chip in off by one pin location - perhaps that happened?

Comment: Maybe you're seeing the effects of a glitch on the reset or set signals you're generating from the AND gates.  Even synchronous counters can have some variation in when the outputs all switch and, depending on the path delays through you combinatorial set/rest circuit (the AND gates), can cause glitches on the output.  You need to register (clock) the set & reset outputs before applying them to the counters, unless the device your using says it has synchronous CLEAR (reset) and LOAD (set) functions.

Comment: _"if one of them is broken the output should not be right in any case."_ No! If one of the IC's is broken, or just one port of one of them, the final output would be right in situations where the failed IC (or the failed port of one of them) is not used. Can you test each one of the 74LS08 ports alone? Did you earthed the unused port?

Comment: And, schematics are always helpful.

Comment: Have you the digital source before chips? If no, may be your case is switch-jitter. see http://www.embedded.com/solving-switch-bounce-problems/